# Mac installation disk

Tags: macos, mac

I have a mac mini and a macbook. I lost the OS X installation DVD for my macbook. would it be ok to use the disk I have for my Mac Mini?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will most likely not work. The disks shipped with the Macs are hardware specific. Use a retail (e.g. Snow Leopard 29$) disk, if you have one.

Comment: D'oh, beat me by a minute.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the build number of Mac OS that is on that Installation DVD (printed on the DVD). If that number is higher than the OS version your Macbook shipped with, everything will work without problems, just make sure to install Mac OS X Software Updates afterwards!

Or in short: If the Mini is "younger" than your MacBook, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Connect a firewire cable between the MacBook and the Mac Mini, then boot the MacBook holding the "T" key to start it in target disk mode. The MacBook will show up on the Mac Mini as an external disk, then you can use [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7032/carbon-copy-cloner) or [SuperDuper!](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13803/superduper!) to clone the Mini's HDD to the MacBook.