# Install mac os x

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mac installation disk](https://superuser.com/questions/231075/mac-installation-disk)
>   [Installing Mac OS X with a different disc](https://superuser.com/questions/220086/installing-mac-os-x-with-a-different-disc)

My friend jus bought a new mac book pro and installed with snow leopard. Is that possible i use her OS Disk to upgrade my mac book from leopard to snow leopard?

Answer (score 1):

Only with the retail disk (the one with the leopard on the front) but the grey disks are computer specific so only if you have the same computer will it work.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that it would be illegal.